# Moved to SonarQube 6.7 so not able to find from where we can get issues fixed in one go

Tags: sonarqube

We were initially using Sonar 5.* version.
When we fixed or introduced any issue on the dashboard page itself we got the status that how many issues are fixed or resolved.

However after the UI has been changed in latest version on the home page we don't the get count of how many issues fixed. We have to go to Activity tab then set date range and then graph shows the information on hower

Our requirement is to capture a screenshot and send mail automatically. So with new upgrade we are currently not able to achieve that as the information is not fetched by giving URL in code

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to depend on the UI of a tool to build your own tool on top of it, using the API seems a better idea in my opinion.

In your case, I would recommend you to use the web service `api/issues/search?componentKeys=PROJECT_KEY& resolutions=FIXED`, you'll be able to get the number of fixed issues by getting the value from `total` of the `paging` node.